# How to disable modifying .csproj file from being modified when saving .resx file in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, resx

I have created a C# console application with Visual Studio 2022. I have added multiple .resx files and I have modified my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**/*.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".Designer", "")).resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="**/*.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".resx", ".Designer.cs"))</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The point of this is that all VS creates .Designer.cs file for every .resx file in the project without the need for explicitly defining it for each .resx file. This works fine.

The problem is as soon as I modify any resource file in Visual Studio 2022, it modifies the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**/*.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".Designer", "")).resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="**/*.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".resx", ".Designer.cs"))</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resource1.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resource1.resx">
      <LastGenOutput>Resource1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It adds the explicit mention of the changed resource file, which I do not want or need.

Is there a way to disable this, preferably through a .csproj setting, or by changing some Visual Studio setting?

Comment: Does [this](https://edi.wang/post/2019/5/14/stop-generating-designercs-for-resx-files-in-net-core) what you need?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to disable Visual Studio from modifying the project file.

Visual Studio doesn't understand the wildcard based definitions.

The expected pattern is to use Visual Studio to add each existing .resx and .Designer.cs file to the project which will create separate entries for each file in the project file.

Edit the .resx entries to add the `Generator` metadata. Edit the .Designer.cs entries to add the `AutoGen` and `DependentUpon` metadata, e.g.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resource1.resx">
      <LastGenOutput>Resource1.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resource1.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resource1.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Edit the project file to remove the wildcard based definitions:

```xml
  <!-- Remove >>> -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**/*.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".Designer", "")).resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="**/*.resx">
      <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>$([System.String]::Copy("%(Filename)").Replace(".resx", ".Designer.cs"))</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- <<< Remove -->
```

In the comments you mention that the number of resource files can be very large. Instead of adding every file individually, a target can be defined to run `BeforeBuild` to add all the resource files that have not already been included in the `EmbeddedResource` ItemGroup and to add the corresponding .Designer.cs that have not already been included to the `Compile` ItemGroup. This doesn't prevent individual file entries but if resource file edits are rare this will keep the project file size low.

Comment: Obviously that would work, but that's not what I wanted to accomplish. My goal was to avoid bloated .csproj file in cases where I have large amount of .resx files (I'm taliking >1000).

Comment: If you edit the project within the Visual Studio IDE, Visual Studio will add individual entries per file. You can't prevent that. But you can add a target that adds `EmbeddedResource` and `Compile` items that are not already in the respective ItemGroups.